# How to display data from many-to-many relationship using odata $expand?

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a few database tables where some of them have many-to-many relationships. I'm using webapi and odata to fetch the data from the database. For instance:

```
TableA ---> TableB (one to one)
TableA ---> TableC (one to one)
TableA ---> TableD (one to one)
TableE --> TableD ---> Table F (many-to-many)
```

Now, since I'm using odata controller, I can use `/odata/Claims?$expand=TableA,TableB,TableC,TableD` which displays the data as it is expected. However, I can't display data from `TableE` and `TableF` using Id's from `TableD`. I'm not sure what code to show you, but here's the `GET` method

```
   [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions =  System.Web.OData.Query.AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    public IQueryable<TableA> Get()
    {
        return dbContext.DeniedClaims.AsQueryable();               
    }
```

Is there any way I can show the data from TableE and TableF in the same query using odata?

This is how the data shows up when I do the `$expand`

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:58891/odata/$metadata#TableA","value":[
    {
      // some values,
      "Id": 1, // blah blah
      "TableB":{
          "Id":1,"FirstName":"Test","LastName":"Test",
      },"TableC":{
        "Id":1,
      },"TableD":{
        "Id":1,"TableERefId":1,"TableFRefId":1
      }
    }
}
```

Note `TableD`, instead of only displaying me `TableERefId` and `TableFRefId`, I want to see the values in `TableE` and `TableF`.

How can I do this?

Comment: FYI, the single `TableERefId` in the JSON shown above suggests that there is a 1:1 relationship between `TableD` and `TableE`. Same goes for `TableD` and `TableF`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your data model correctly, you want to do inline expansion more than 1 level deep. Assuming that the `TableD` entity type has navigation properties named `TableE` and `TableF`, append a [nested `$expand` option](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398298) to `TableD` as follows:

```
$expand=TableB,TableC,TableD($expand=TableE,TableF)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I didn't know `$expand` could be used like this. This is an important lesson for me. Thank you.